# How to have a variable number of Bluebird Promises? (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, response, bluebird

I have an empty array of documents.

```
let arrayOfDocuments = [];
```

I want to call http requests (using superagent) to download a text file and put its contents into my arrayOfDocuments.

```
request.get('docs.google.com/document/d/SOME_FILE_NAME').then((res) => {
    arrayOfDocuments.push(res.text);
});
```

That part I get, but here is the tricky part. I want to put this in a for loop and do something after the for loop. So like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numOfLinks; i++) {
    // send the http requests as above
}

//do stuff here but only after the above for loop is finished.
```

How do I only do the last line if the loop is finished? The way my program is running right now, the code after the for loop runs before the http requests get a response and finish. I think there is a way to do this using Bluebird Promises, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html).

Comment: How do I get the responses of each of the requests sent though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `promise.all` as shown here http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

In practice it might look something like:

```
var promises = []
var links = ['a.com/a', 'a.com/b']

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    promises.push(request.get(links[i])
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(allRes) {
    //do anything you want with allRes or iterate
    for (var promise in promises){
      promise.then(function(singleRes){/*do something with each promise after all resolve*/}
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I get the responses of each of these requests though? Like I want to check the type of each response (res.type) to do a slightly different thing with different types.

Comment: in then method is accesible an array of the responses ordered by the array of promises.

Comment: What's i then method?

Comment: You can simplify your code doing Promise.all(links.map(link=>request.get(link)).then(arrayOfResponses=>/*Do whatever*/);

Comment: Okay thank you!! Your edit with the responses made it very clear!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo thought about that, but I try not to assume familiarity with map/forEach/filter functions. They confuse some people while for loops (while ugly and over verbose in this case) are more recognizable. You are totally right and I would prefer your line in real code.

Comment: The difference between `.map()` and `.all()` is that with `.map()` you can set the `concurrency` option to something more real. `.all()` will try to resolve all promises at once, that might not be convenient if you have a large list on that array, and depends on the type of resource you are accessing. If you don't know how many items there will be on the initial array, then it might be a good idea to set up `concurrency` to a value that suits.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) method:

```
Promise.map(arrayOfLinks, function(link) {
  return request.get(link);
}).then(function(arrayOfDocuments) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Depending on your situation (particularly if you don't care about handling individual promises and just want the collection of all the promises) this solution can be better than mine. I was unclear after reading the question if this was case (and still am) hence the more general approach presented in my answer.